# Install symfony project using sudo or not

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am learning how to use the Symfony framework to do PHP web applications. When you install a new project, it warns me because it cannot create cache repository because is not writable. But when I start a new project with *sudo* keyword, the terminal complain about running the *composer* as a root/user.

So I don't know if I start a new project using *sudo* keyword or not? What is the correct?

[image: terminal]

Comment: You don't use sudo. You run it as your web user (www-data if you haven't changed it)

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0):

You actually can use sudo when using composer in spite of the warning.  The resulting project will work just fine.

I ran into this after installing a linux subsystem under Windows 10.  For some reason my $HOME/.composer directory ended up being owned by root.  I guess it was a byproduct of the composer install process.  I didn't bother to figure out why for awhile.  Just used sudo.

But it would be better to go ahead and just fix the directory using basic linux commands:

```
cd $HOME
sudo find .composer -exec chown myusername {} \;
sudo find .composer -exec chgrp myusername {} \;
```

And that should take care of the problem.